# How to return two rows from one during a 2D array map in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, rows, array-map

I'm trying to take census data I receive from a spreadsheet and convert it to a 2D array to do my cleaning to it. Unfortunately, not all sheets I receive are formatted the same, and thus I am trying to make the script be able to work with multiple formats. I have it working when there is one line per person, but when I get one line per dependent and multiple per employee my script does not return the desired results.

Working Example inputs:

```
[
   ["LstNm",    "1st Nm",   "Email",    "EE-SSN",   "Mem-SSN","Relate"]
   ["Smith",    "John",     "a@a.com",  11, 11, "E"]
   ["Wang",     "Jacob",    "a@a.com",  11, 22, "C"]
   ["Da Silva", "Jingle",   "c@c.org",  13, 13, "E"]
   ["Martin",   "Heimer",   "b@b.net",  12, 12, "E"]
   ["Muller",   "Schmidt",  "b@b.net",  12, 22, "S"]
]
```

Problem Inputs. This is where I want to return two rows, one for the employee, and one for the dependent. But in my code's present state, it is not working:

```
[
   ["LstNm",    "1stNm",    "Email", "EE-SSN", "Mem-SSN", "Relate", "DepLstNm", "Dep1stNm", "Dep-SSN",  "Dep-Relate"]
   ["Smith",    "John",     "a@a.com",  11, 11, "E",      "Wang",   "Jacob",    21, "C"]
   ["Da Silva", "Jingle",   "c@c.org",  13, 13, "E",    ,   ,   ,   ]
   ["Martin",   "Heimer",   "b@b.net",  12, 12, "E",      "Muller", "Schmidt",  22, "S"]
]
```

The expected end result in both cases would be **One row per person** with the EE-SSN linking the employee to the dependent:

```
[
   ["Email",    "1stNm",    "LstNm",    "EE-SSN",   "Mem-SSN",  "Relate"]
   ["a@a.com",  "John",     "Smith",    11, 11, "E"]
   ["a@a.com",  "Jacob",    "Wang",     11, 22, "C"]
   ["c@c.org",  "Jingle",   "Da Silva", 13, 13, "E"]
   ["b@b.net",  "Heimer",   "Martin",   12, 12, "E"]
   ["b@b.net",  "Schmidt",  "Muller",   12, 22, "S"]
]
```

Finally, here is the code I'm using:

```
function getData(origData, index) {
  var depCheck = index[6]+index[7]+index[8]+index[9]
  if (depCheck < 0) {
    var workData = origData.map(row => ([
      row[index[2]],                      // EMAIL
      row[index[1]],                      // FIRST NAME
      row[index[0]],                      // LAST  NAME
      row[index[3]],                      // SUBSCIBER SSN
      row[index[4]],                      // MEMBER SSN
      row[index[5]],                      // RELATIONSHIP
    ]));
  } else {
    var arr = [[]];
    var workData = origData.flatMap(row => {
      arr.push([
          row[index[2]],                      // EMAIL
          row[index[1]],                      // FIRST NAME
          row[index[0]],                      // LAST  NAME
          row[index[3]],                      // SUBSCIBER SSN
          row[index[4]],                      // MEMBER SSN
          row[index[5]],                      // RELATIONSHIP
        ]);
      if (typeof row[index[6]] !== "undefined" && typeof row[index[8]] !== "undefined" ) {
        arr.push([
          row[index[2]],                      // EMAIL
          row[index[7]],                      // FIRST NAME
          row[index[6]],                      // LAST  NAME
          row[index[3]],                      // SUBSCIBER SSN
          row[index[8]],                      // MEMBER SSN
          row[index[9]],                      // RELATIONSHIP
        ]);
      }
      return arr;
    });
  }
  return workData;
}

function main () {
  const originalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  const origData = originalSheet.getRange("A6:F11").getValues();
  console.log(origData);
  var index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-1,-1,-1];
  var data = getData(origData, index);
  console.log("Single Rows:\n" + data);

  const origData2 = originalSheet.getRange("A13:J16").getValues();
  console.log(origData2);
  var index2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var data2 = getData(origData2, index2);
  console.log("Double Rows:\n" + data2);

  var numRows = data.length;
  var numCols = data[0].length;

  var numRows2 = data2.length;
  var numCols2 = data2[0].length;

  originalSheet.getRange(18,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(data);
  originalSheet.getRange(18,7,numRows2,numCols2).setValues(data2);
}
```

***EDIT*** Reviewing the code further, I realized that by returning a 2D array in the second map which returns `arr[tempEE, tempDep]` is actually becoming a 3D array. As such, I switched the map to flatMap (see answer below), which gives the desired 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, changing the second map to flatMap does fix the problem, here is the final code I used:

```
function getData(origData, index) {  
  var depCheck = index[6]+index[7]+index[8]+index[9]
  if (depCheck < 0) {
    var workData = origData.map(row => ([ // The data is simply returned as a 1D arr here
      row[index[2]],                      // EMAIL
      row[index[1]],                      // FIRST NAME
      row[index[0]],                      // LAST  NAME
      row[index[3]],                      // SUBSCIBER SSN
      row[index[4]],                      // MEMBER SSN
      row[index[5]],                      // RELATIONSHIP
    ]));
  } else {
    var arr = [];
    /** Use flatMap here as the returned arr[tempEE, tempDep] is a 2D array being added to an 
      * array workData[arr], flatMap takes the result and flattens it by one level*/
    var workData = origData.flatMap(row => {
      var tempEE = [
          row[index[2]],                      // EMAIL
          row[index[1]],                      // FIRST NAME
          row[index[0]],                      // LAST  NAME
          row[index[3]],                      // SUBSCIBER SSN
          row[index[4]],                      // MEMBER SSN
          row[index[5]],                      // RELATIONSHIP
        ];
      if (typeof row[index[6]] !== "undefined" && typeof row[index[8]] !== "undefined" ) {
        console.log("Dependent - " + row[index[6]])
        var tempDep = [
          row[index[2]],                      // EMAIL
          row[index[7]],                      // FIRST NAME
          row[index[6]],                      // LAST  NAME
          row[index[3]],                      // SUBSCIBER SSN
          row[index[8]],                      // MEMBER SSN
          row[index[9]],                      // RELATIONSHIP
        ];
      }
      var arr = [tempEE, tempDep];
      return arr;
    });
  }
  return workData;
}

function main () {
  const originalSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  const origData = originalSheet.getRange("A6:F11").getValues();
  console.log(origData);
  var index = [0,1,2,3,4,5,-1,-1,-1,-1];
  var data = getData(origData, index);
  console.log("Single Rows:\n" + data);

  const origData2 = originalSheet.getRange("A13:J16").getValues();
  console.log(origData2);
  var index2 = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
  var data2 = getData(origData2, index2);
  console.log("Double Rows:\n" + data2);

  var numRows = data.length;
  var numCols = data[0].length;

  var numRows2 = data2.length;
  var numCols2 = data2[0].length;

  originalSheet.getRange(18,1,numRows,numCols).setValues(data);
  originalSheet.getRange(18,7,numRows2,numCols2).setValues(data2);
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

Here is a revised example of how to use array functions to break the employee/dependant row into 2 seperate rows .  This example assumes there is only one dependant per employee.

**Script**

```
function testCensus() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Census");
    let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    values.forEach( row => Logger.log(row) );
    let header = values.shift();  // remove the header row
    let results = [[].concat(header[2],header[1],header[0],header.slice(3,6))];
    function sort(row) {
      let temp = [].concat(row[2],row[1],row[0],row.slice(3,6));
      results.push(temp);
      if( row[6] !== '' ) {
        temp = [].concat(row[2],row[7],row[6],row[3],row.slice(-2));
        results.push(temp);
      }
    }
    values.forEach( row => sort(row) );
    results.forEach( row => Logger.log(row) );
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in testCensus - "+err)
  }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
10:04:57 AM Notice  Execution started
10:04:58 AM Info    [LstNm, 1stNm, Email, EE-SSN, Mem-SSN, Relate, DepLstNm, Dep1stNm, Dep-SSN, Dep-Relate]
10:04:58 AM Info    [Smith, John, a@a.com, 11.0, 11.0, E, Wang, Jacob, 21.0, C]
10:04:58 AM Info    [Da Silva, Jingle, c@c.org, 13.0, 13.0, E, , , , ]
10:04:58 AM Info    [Martin, Heimer, b@b.net, 12.0, 12.0, E, Muller, Schmidt, 22.0, S]

10:04:58 AM Info    [Email, 1stNm, LstNm, EE-SSN, Mem-SSN, Relate]
10:04:58 AM Info    [a@a.com, John, Smith, 11.0, 11.0, E]
10:04:58 AM Info    [a@a.com, Jacob, Wang, 11.0, 21.0, C]
10:04:58 AM Info    [c@c.org, Jingle, Da Silva, 13.0, 13.0, E]
10:04:58 AM Info    [b@b.net, Heimer, Martin, 12.0, 12.0, E]
10:04:58 AM Info    [b@b.net, Schmidt, Muller, 12.0, 22.0, S]
10:04:58 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: @TheWizEnd, Sorry if my question was confusing, but the result I am trying to get is more the inverse. I'm trying to take the data from 1 row per employee & associated dependent to 1 row per person, where the dependent maintains the *employee's SSN* as their association.  The end result I am looking for is the third 2D array listed above, containing 6 rows (including header) and 6 columns.